# how to show logged in members username in wordpress content

Tags: users

I'm working on a page on a site but got stuck at this point I want to show the logged in members username/first name of the site content for that I'm using this code

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    <!-- text that logged in users will see -->
<?php global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo(); ?>
<h5>Hi <?php echo $current_user->user_firstname; ?></h5>
<p>You have access to all of the free members stuff, enjoy :) <a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout"> Logout </a></p>
<?php } ?>
```

but instead of showing the username i shows broken code like this [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tWfL.png). I'm creating the page with WPBakery.

Comment: @fuxia that answer didn't work for me

Comment: What happens when you replace `<h5>Hi <?php echo $current_user->user_firstname; ?></h5>` with `<h5>Hi <?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?></h5>` or with `<h5>Hi <?php echo "Foobar"; ?></h5>`? Still weird output? Then something else in your code somewhere else is broken.

Comment: i see this https://i.imgur.com/JwPooHw.png

Comment: Yes, I got that. It's the same screenshot as in your question. But what happens when you replace it with the code I suggested?

Comment: nothing changes

Comment: I used the same ss because nothing actually happens

Comment: What? You do `echo "Foobar"` and get this? Then there's something else broken beyond the snippet you provided.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$current_user->user_firstname` contains some tag content.

I would replace that line with:

```
<h5>Hi <?php echo esc_html($current_user->user_firstname); ?></h5>
```

or

```
<h5>Hi <?php echo strip_tags($current_user->user_firstname); ?></h5>
```

One of those (or either) may solve your problem outright.

Comment: Nope it didn't work

Comment: @YasirRehman – What does didn't work mean exactly?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JwPooHw.png this is how it looks like